# find | xargs sed to substitute string in file name instead of file content

Tags: sed, xargs

```
$ echo "file_contents" > filename.txt
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed 's/file//g'
_contents
```

How do you get sed to treat the filename as a string instead of an input file? What command do I need to get "`name.txt`" as the output instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `xargs` and `-0`'s.

```
find . -type f  | sed 's/file//g'
```

This takes the output of `find` and sends it as input to `sed`.

Comment: ah of course. Must be having a brainfart today